# Android getIntent() in parent class returns null

Tags: android

Here is an `Annotation` class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface InjectExtra {
    public String value();
}
```

Here's the class that deals with the `Annotation` class: `InjectActivity`:

```
public class InjectActivity extends Activity {
   protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

      handleAnnotation();
   }

   private void handleAnnotation(){
      final Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //TODO here always null!!why?

      if(fields == null || fields.length <= 0 || extras == null) {
        return;
      }

      for(final Field field : fields) {
        if(field.isAnnotationPresent(InjectExtra.class)) {
          field.setAccessible(true);

          final InjectExtra injectExtra = field.<InjectExtra>
            getAnnotation(InjectExtra.class); 

          field.set(object, extras.get(injectExtra.value()));
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Now here is where I am trying to use the `InjectActivity`:

```
public class SimpleActivity extends InjectActivity{
  @InjectExtra("id")
  private String id;

  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    ...
  }
}
```

When I try to start this activity, it doesn't work:

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this,SimpleActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", "kai");
startActivity(i);
```

This is because `getIntent().getExtras()` in `InjectActivity` is always `null`. However, when I move the method `handleAnnotation` from `InjectActivity` to `SimpleActivity`, it works!

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this peace of code :**

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this,SimpleActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", "kai");
startActivity(i);
```

**With this peace of code:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this,SimpleActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", "kai");
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i)
```